# nth-child(even/odd) not working and border-collapse issue

Tags: html, css

I've got a problem with styling my table. Now the part of my table looks like this:
[table look now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pyjU.jpg)

And I would like it to look this way in the end:
[end table. This green color is for hover which I'm going to take care of later](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGRSE.png)

1)I know I should use "border-collapse: collapse" to erase those lines between the rows and columns, but when I do it my triangles in the end of rows (which are made of borders) loose their shape.

2)When I want to have my triangles in a different shades of grey (suitable for rows on their left side) and I am using even or odd it doesn't working and all traingles are in one color.

I am adding my code here:

```css
.top10 table td:nth-child(2){
    width:50vw;
}
.top10 table td:nth-child(3){
    width:10vw;
}
.top10 table{
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color:black;
}
.top10 table tr:nth-child(odd){
    background-color: #636368;
}
.top10 table tr:nth-child(even){
    background-color: #c4cad5;
}

.top10 table #triangle2:nth-child(odd){
    background-color:#fff;
    width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 25px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
  border-left: 120px solid #636368;
}
.top10 table #triangle2:nth-child(even){
    background-color:#fff;
    width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 25px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
  border-left: 120px solid #c4cad5;
}
```

```html
              <div class="top10 center">
                <div class="headerBox">
                    <h2>RANKING TOP 10</h2>
                </div>
                <table>
                    <tr><td>1.</td> <td><a>Lorem Ipsum</a></td> <td><strong>8,74</strong></td> <td>5 126 głosów</td> <td id="triangle2"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td>2.</td> <td><a>Lorem Ipsum</a></td> <td><strong>8,74</strong></td> <td>5 126 głosów</td> <td id="triangle2"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td>3.</td> <td><a>Lorem Ipsum</a></td> <td><strong>8,74</strong></td> <td>5 126 głosów</td> <td id="triangle2"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td>4.</td> <td><a>Lorem Ipsum</a></td> <td><strong>8,74</strong></td> <td>5 126 głosów</td> <td id="triangle2"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td>5.</td> <td><a>Lorem Ipsum</a></td> <td><strong>8,74</strong></td> <td>5 126 głosów</td> <td id="triangle2"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td>6.</td> <td><a>Lorem Ipsum</a></td> <td><strong>8,74</strong></td> <td>5 126 głosów</td> <td id="triangle2"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td>7.</td> <td><a>Lorem Ipsum</a></td> <td><strong>8,74</strong></td> <td>5 126 głosów</td> <td id="triangle2"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td>8.</td> <td><a>Lorem Ipsum</a></td> <td><strong>8,74</strong></td> <td>5 126 głosów</td> <td id="triangle2"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td>9.</td> <td><a>Lorem Ipsum</a></td> <td><strong>8,74</strong></td> <td>5 126 głosów</td> <td id="triangle2"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td>10.</td> <td><a>Lorem Ipsum</a></td> <td><strong>8,74</strong></td>> <td>5 126 głosów</td> <td id="triangle2"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working is just that you are `styling` directly `td` elements instead use `even and odd` on `tr` and then style there `child elements` which are here `td #triangle`.

```
.top10  table  tr:nth-child(odd)  #triangle2{
................
................
................
}
.top10  table  tr:nth-child(even)  #triangle2{
................
................
................
}
```

> border-collapse : collapse - Collapse table border into single-border.

```css
.top10 table td:nth-child(2){
    width:50vw;
}
.top10 table td:nth-child(3){
    width:10vw;
}
.top10 table{
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color:black;
}
.top10 table tr:nth-child(odd){
    background-color: #636368;
}
.top10 table tr:nth-child(even){
    background-color: #c4cad5;
}

.top10  table  tr:nth-child(odd)  #triangle2{
  background-color:#fff;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 25px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
  border-left: 120px solid blue;
}
.top10  table  tr:nth-child(even)  #triangle2{
    background-color:#fff;
    width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 25px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
  border-left: 120px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="top10 center">
 <div class="headerBox">
 <h2>RANKING TOP 10</h2>
 </div>
<table>
<tr><td>1.</td> <td><a>Lorem Ipsum</a></td> <td><strong>8,74</strong></td> <td>5 126 głosów</td> <td id="triangle2"></td>
</tr>
<tr><td>2.</td> <td><a>Lorem Ipsum</a></td> <td><strong>8,74</strong></td> <td>5 126 głosów</td> <td id="triangle2"></td>
</tr>
<tr><td>3.</td> <td><a>Lorem Ipsum</a></td> <td><strong>8,74</strong></td> <td>5 126 głosów</td> <td id="triangle2"></td>             </tr>
                    <tr><td>4.</td> <td><a>Lorem Ipsum</a></td> <td><strong>8,74</strong></td> <td>5 126 głosów</td> <td id="triangle2"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td>5.</td> <td><a>Lorem Ipsum</a></td> <td><strong>8,74</strong></td> <td>5 126 głosów</td> <td id="triangle2"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td>6.</td> <td><a>Lorem Ipsum</a></td> <td><strong>8,74</strong></td> <td>5 126 głosów</td> <td id="triangle2"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td>7.</td> <td><a>Lorem Ipsum</a></td> <td><strong>8,74</strong></td> <td>5 126 głosów</td> <td id="triangle2"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td>8.</td> <td><a>Lorem Ipsum</a></td> <td><strong>8,74</strong></td> <td>5 126 głosów</td> <td id="triangle2"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td>9.</td> <td><a>Lorem Ipsum</a></td> <td><strong>8,74</strong></td> <td>5 126 głosów</td> <td id="triangle2"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td>10.</td> <td><a>Lorem Ipsum</a></td> <td><strong>8,74</strong></td>> <td>5 126 głosów</td> <td id="triangle2"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

Comment: And what do you think I should do with this border-collapse? Couse it's still ruining my triangles ;)

Comment: @JustynaSkrajna You could add border-collapse to table and that even breaks your triangle at end, so you could use pseudo selector as in this jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jp67n1vj/1/ and do accept if it works.

Comment: I had to adjust triangles a few pixels, but it works great. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome @JustynaSkrajna :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this. I only tried on chrome, but it appeared to be good.

```css
/* 1) */
.top10 table tr {
  display: inline-flex;
}

/* 2) */
.top10 table tr:nth-child(odd) #triangle2 {
  background-color:#fff;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 25px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
  border-left: 120px solid #636368;
}
.top10 table tr:nth-child(even) #triangle2 {
  background-color:#fff;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 25px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
  border-left: 120px solid #c4cad5;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's almost right. The second issue is solved, but I would also want to have it justified, like at the beginning. Because of inline-flex I'm loosing this table layout ( Sorry, my end-table-image can be misguiding at this point)

Comment: You should define a precise width for each <td> (or just the td you want to), so everything will fit in its own container without moving other elements. (=> every element of a column will be aligned with the other elements of this same column.)